# How would I fix Cannot read properties of undefined error and a possible memory leak in this react Application?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am fairly new to react and am having trouble handling data refreshes properly.

What I want to happen:

1. User Releases/Rejects a case by calling updateCase
2. This triggers a call to getCaseDetail to retrieve the updated caseInformation to display
3. getCaseNotes API is called to display the notes attached to a case

The basic structure of my app;

```
export function SubmissionsCaseDetail({caseDetail, setCurrentCaseDetail}) {

  const [caseUpdateDtls, setCaseUpdateDtls] = useState({});

  const { run: getCaseNotes } = useFetchye(`${subApiUrl}/case/notes/${caseDetail.caseNumber}`, {
    defer: true,
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: getDefaultHeaders(),
    method: 'GET',
  });

  const { run: updateCase } = useFetchye(`${subApiUrl}/case/update`, {
    defer: true,
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: getDefaultHeaders(),
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(caseUpdateDtls),
  });

  const { run: getCaseDetail } = useFetchye(`${subApiUrl}/case/search`, {
    defer: true,
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: getDefaultHeaders(),
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      case_number: caseDetail.caseNumber,
    }),
  });
}

  const refreshCaseDetail = async () => {
    const { data } = await getCaseDetail();
    if (data.status === 200) {
      const caseDetailResult = transformSubmissionsCases(data.body);
      setCurrentCaseDetail(caseDetailResult.caseDetails[caseDetail.caseNumber]);
      refreshClicNotes();
    } else {
      setResponseMsg('Error in retrieving case detail');
    }
  };

  const callUpdateCase = async () => {
    const { data } = await updateCase();
    if (data.status === 200) {
      setResponseMsg('Case Updated Successfully');
      refreshCaseDetail();
    } else {
      setResponseMsg('Error updating case.');
    }
    setCaseUpdateDtls({});
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(caseUpdateDtls).length !== 0) {
      callUpdateCase();
    }
  }, [caseUpdateDtls]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{caseDetail.caseNumber}</div>
      <div>{caseDetail.caseStatus}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I try to update the case, I see the below error:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'caseNumber')` at ``` const { run: getCaseNotes } = useFetchye(``${subApiUrl}/case/notes/${caseDetail.caseNumber} ```,

I also see this in the console:
`Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`

What am I missing here?